# How to display data to a JtextArea in java with exact text alignment same from the txt file

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextarea

[image: This is the exact alignment from the text file]

When I append the data to the JTextArea in Java it does not copy the alignment.

[image: This is the image of the text area and the alignment is very different from the txt file.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be 2 problems at hand. If your original textfile is using Tabs instead of spaces to align its columns the way it does, you need to set the same tab size on your `JTextArea` component.

See [JavaDoc for setTabSize(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setTabSize(int))

Secondly, alignment can only really be achieved with a mono-sapced font (where every character has the same visual width).

See [JavaDoc for setFont(Font)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setFont(java.awt.Font))

I just found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16279950/8383428) by Guillaume Polet where he describes the way to get a general-purpose monospace font by simply specifying `monospaced` as the font's name:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(24, 80);
textArea.setFont(new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 12));
```

Comment: I am currently using this format to write data to txt file

Comment: String format = "%-15s %-15s %-15s";

Comment: it goes exactly to text file but when retrieve again and put to jtextarea the alignment is not correct.

Comment: So you enter the text in a `JTextArea`, save it to a `.txt` file by using the above formatting String and then you load it back into the `JTextArea` but with the worng alignment?

Comment: No i put some data to the txt file first then i retrieve them again via jtextarea.

Comment: Okay, please try out my suggested fixes and comment again if those don't fix your problem.

Comment: I write a file first then I retrieved/append them to JTextArea.

Comment: the second one worked for me and I already upvoted your answer. thanks a lot.